# C# code acts wrong unless debugging

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

So I have been working on my C# project which required to do some serial communication. Everything was working fine until I have one really... weird issue.

So right now I am recieving a code in serial which is stored in myString. Then below where I get the issue which is that if I am not debugging the code then a whole if statement just... get ignored. However when I use a breakpoint it does everything right. For referance everything here works except the part of (*l) 
(the rest of the code was removed for needless parts. I can attach more if you guys think it can help.)

```
public delegate void AddDataDelegate(String myString);
public AddDataDelegate myDelegate;
//
//
this.myDelegate = new AddDataDelegate(AddDataMethod);

//
//
private void Receiver(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
{
    Byte[] str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(comPort.ReadExisting());

    this.Invoke(this.myDelegate, new Object[] 
    { 
         System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(str)
    });

}
//  

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (connectionStatus.Text == "Connected")
    {
        comPort.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            comPort.PortName = port;
            comPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
            comPort.DataBits = dataBits;
            comPort.StopBits = (StopBits)stopBits;
            comPort.Parity = parity;
            comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Receiver);

            comPort.Open();
            connectionButton.Text = "Disconnect";
            connectionStatus.Text = "Connected";

        }
        catch
        {
            comPort.Close();
        }
    }
}


public void AddDataMethod(String myString)
{
    try
    {
        string colorSensorValue;
        string distanceSensorValue;
        string proximitySwitch;
        string limitSwitch;
        if (myString.Contains("*c*"))
        {
            string[] colors;
            int red;
            int blue;
            int green;
            int max;
            colorSensorValue = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("*c*") + 3);
            if (colorSensorValue.Contains("*e")) colorSensorValue = colorSensorValue.Substring(0, colorSensorValue.IndexOf("*e*"));
            colors = colorSensorValue.Split(',');
            red = Convert.ToInt16(colors[0]);
            green = Convert.ToInt16(colors[1]);
            blue = Convert.ToInt16(colors[2]);

            max = Math.Max(red, Math.Max(green, blue));
            red = red * 255 / max;
            blue = blue * 255 / max;
            green = green * 255 / max;
            color.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(red,blue,green);
            colorSensorTextBox.Text = (colorSensorValue);
        }
        if (myString.Contains("*d"))
        {
            distanceSensorValue = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("*d*") + 3);
            if (distanceSensorValue.Contains("*e")) distanceSensorValue = distanceSensorValue.Substring(0, distanceSensorValue.IndexOf("*e*"));
            distanceSensorTextBox.Text = (distanceSensorValue);
        }
        if (myString.Contains("*l"))
        {
            limitSwitch = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("*l*") + 3);
            if (limitSwitch.Contains("*e")) limitSwitch = limitSwitch.Substring(0, limitSwitch.IndexOf("*e*"));
            limitRead.Text = limitSwitch;
        }
        if (myString.Contains("*p"))
        {
            proximitySwitch = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf("*p*") + 3);
            if (proximitySwitch.Contains("*e")) proximitySwitch = proximitySwitch.Substring(0, proximitySwitch.IndexOf("*e*"));
            proximityRead.Text = proximitySwitch;
        }

        comPort.BaseStream.Flush();

    }
    catch
    {

    }

}
```

Example of myString:

```
*c*96,84,75*e**d*25.5*e**p*0*e**l*0*e*
```

so it will be read as:
colors: 96 , 84 , 75 (happens right!)
distance: 25.5 (happens right!)
prox : 0 (happens right!)
limit : 0 (doesnt happen..)

note that order of both sent and received data doesn't change which one (limit) that doesn't work unless I breakpoint

Comment: it's some kind of multi-threading issue

Comment: Any clue of how I can solve it

Comment: add the code you use to receive the string. are you using ReceiveData event?

Comment: Put System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation or log in each of the `if`s, run the code in Release (i.e. not from VS). See if it behaves correctly.

Comment: it will not be convenient at all to run it on release since I will need to debug a lot. How exactly do I do the other two? Details would be appreciated.

Comment: @mcNets yes. I will add the complete code now.

Comment: `comPort.DataReceived += AddDataMethod`?

Comment: yea I have it just slightly below. Forgot to add it here .

Comment: can you paste some example of myString value?

Answer (score 1):

According the [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx): class information in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is
>   received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a
>   secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some
>   elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a
>   threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main
>   Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do
>   the work on the proper thread.

You should use use this form:

```
this.Invoke(this.AddDataMethod, new Object[] { The_Received_String });
                    }
```

Comment: so I just add ".Parent" to that part?

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied and paste from my code. I have a general purpose serial class.

Comment: The weird part is that it only skips that specific IF even when I changed the order of the IF statements. Thanks for trying anyway!